# How should I write this mongodb query using group by

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I  want to find out if a restaurant has valet service, the number of restaurants with them that have 5 star ratings, 4 stars, 3 stars, etc. So the output would be like in my mongodb database, for all restaurants that have valet service, here are the numbers of restaurants at each review level:

5 stars: 124 restaurants have this rating and valet service
4.5 stars: 356
4 stars: 345
etc.

So far this what I can think of, want give some guidance

```
db.YOURCOLLECTIONNAME.aggregate([{$match: {"attributes": /.*valet: True.*/i}}, ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match: {"attributes": /.*valet': True.*/i}},{$group: {_id: "$stars", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

FYI https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/